# generate Toned voices

Tags: voice-recognition, audio

I need to do some thing like : get a clip of my voice for example and extarct a voice print from it and then use it to generate sound that has "MY" tone

a hint or an idea or something that does a similar thing would really helpful

Comment: I think there's a jQuery plugin for that

Answer (score 0):

Try using [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net)